# Using switch statement for Word doc selection

Tags: c#

i currently have a program that merges word docs' depending on user selection. Currently the program allows a total of 5 files to be selected for merging via a button press, as shown:

```
 // combine files in folder selected using MsWord.cs, 
    private void combineButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadingForm.Show(); // displays 'loading' form

        // 5 documents selected by the user
        selectedDocs = new [] 
            {
            selectedFile1,
            selectedFile2,
            selectedFile3,
            selectedFile4,
            selectedFile5
            };

        string fileDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
        // output folder user selects            
        string outcomeFolder2 = outputFolder2; 

        string outputFile2 = "Combined Files " + fileDate + " @ " + fileTime + ".docx";
        string outputFileName2 = Path.Combine(outcomeFolder2, outputFile2);

        MsWord.Merge(selectedDocs, outputFileName2, true);
        loadingForm.Hide(); // to hide the form

        // Message displaying how many files are combined. 
        MessageBox.Show("A total of " + selectedDocs.Length.ToString() + " documents have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

the current issue is, the user *MUST* select 5 documents. If they choose 2/3/4 files the program errors, which limits overall usage. I was reading into Switch statements which may help remedy the situation however i am not not knowledgeable with the command. I assuming it will go something like:

```
 switch (merge)
     {
        case 'selectedFile1':
           selectedDocs = new [selectedFile1] 
           break;
        case 'selectedFile2':
           selectedDocs = new [selectedFile1, selectedFile2] 
           break;
        case 'selectedFile3':
           selectedDocs = new [selectedFile1, selectedFile2, selectedFile3] 
           break;
        case 'selectedFile4':
           selectedDocs = new [selectedFile1, selectedFile2, selectedFile3, selectedFile4] 
           break;
        case 'selectedFile5':
           selectedDocs = new [selectedFile1, selectedFile2, selectedFile3, selectedFile4, selectedFile5]                
           break;

           default:
        MessageBox.Show("error, no files selected");
           break;
     }
```

** updated information **

```
    // input Destination - for separate files
    private string[] selectedDocs;
    // input file 1
    string selectedFile1;
    private void browseFileButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileInput1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileInput1.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx;*.doc";
        openFileInput1.Title = "Select a Word Document";

        // Default file, altered when the user selects file of choice 
        openFileInput1.FileName = selectedFile1;

        // initial file path display
        filePath1.Text = openFileInput1.FileName;

        // 'OK' button being confirmed on the popup menu
        if (openFileInput1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFile1 = openFileInput1.FileName;
            filePath1.Text = openFileInput1.FileName;
        }
    }

    // input file 2
    string selectedFile2;
    private void browseFileButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileInput2 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileInput2.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx;*.doc";
        openFileInput2.Title = "Select a Word Document";

        // Default file, altered when the user selects file of choice 
        openFileInput2.FileName = selectedFile2;

        // initial file path display
        filePath2.Text = openFileInput2.FileName;

        // 'OK' button being confirmed on the popup menu
        if (openFileInput2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFile2 = openFileInput2.FileName;
            filePath2.Text = openFileInput2.FileName;
        }
    }

    // input file 3
    private string selectedFile3;
    private void browseFileButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileInput3 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileInput3.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx;*.doc";
        openFileInput3.Title = "Select a Word Document";

        // Default file, altered when the user selects file of choice 
        openFileInput3.FileName = selectedFile3;

        // initial file path display
        filePath3.Text = openFileInput3.FileName;

        // 'OK' button being confirmed on the popup menu
        if (openFileInput3.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFile3 = openFileInput3.FileName;
            filePath3.Text = openFileInput3.FileName;
        }
    }

    // input file 4
    private string selectedFile4;
    private void browseFileButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileInput4 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileInput4.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx;*.doc";
        openFileInput4.Title = "Select a Word Document";

        // Default file, altered when the user selects file of choice 
        openFileInput4.FileName = selectedFile4;

        // initial file path display
        filePath4.Text = openFileInput4.FileName;

        // 'OK' button being confirmed on the popup menu
        if (openFileInput4.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFile4 = openFileInput4.FileName;
            filePath4.Text = openFileInput4.FileName;
        }
    }

    // input file 5
    private string selectedFile5;
    private void browseFileButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileInput5 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileInput5.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx;*.doc";
        openFileInput5.Title = "Select a Word Document";

        // Default file, altered when the user selects file of choice 
        openFileInput5.FileName = selectedFile5;

        // initial file path display
        filePath5.Text = openFileInput5.FileName;

        // 'OK' button being confirmed on the popup menu
        if (openFileInput5.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFile5 = openFileInput5.FileName;
            filePath5.Text = openFileInput5.FileName;
        }
    }

    // Output Destination - for separate files
    private string outputFolder2 = @"";
    private void browseButtonOut2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog diagBrowserOutput2 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        diagBrowserOutput2.Description = "Select a folder location to save the document...";

        // Default folder, altered when the user selects folder of choice 
        diagBrowserOutput2.SelectedPath = outputFolder2;

        // Output file path display
        outputPath2.Text = diagBrowserOutput2.SelectedPath;

        if (DialogResult.OK == diagBrowserOutput2.ShowDialog())
        {
            outputFolder2 = diagBrowserOutput2.SelectedPath;
            outputPath2.Text = diagBrowserOutput2.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    // combine files in folder selected using MsWord.cs, 
    private void combineButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadingForm.Show(); // To show the form

        selectedDocs = new [] 
            {
            selectedFile1,
            selectedFile2,
            selectedFile3,
            selectedFile4,
            selectedFile5
            };

        string fileDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string fileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
        string outcomeFolder2 = outputFolder2;
        string outputFile2 = "Combined Files " + fileDate + " @ " + fileTime + ".docx";
        string outputFileName2 = Path.Combine(outcomeFolder2, outputFile2);

        MsWord.Merge(selectedDocs, outputFileName2, true);
        loadingForm.Hide(); // to hide the form

        // Message displaying how many files are combined. 
        MessageBox.Show("A total of " + selectedDocs.Length.ToString() + " documents have been merged", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `List<string>` instead and convert to array at the last moment so it is always the exact right size.

```
List<string> doclist = new List<string>();
doclist.Add(selectedFile1);
//...etc.

//Then...
 MsWord.Merge(doclist.ToArray(), outputFileName2, true);
```

Comment: the selectedDocs are word documents, made up of text essentially. when you say replace Doc with your type, what is it you are suggesting? the program merges 1-5 documents into one combined doc.

Comment: The same `Type` you are putting in the array. Maybe `WordDocument`?

Comment: so essentially, i'll end up with something like this..?

`List<Doc> doclist = new List<Doc>();
doclist.Add(selectedFile1); 
doclist.Add(selectedFile2);
// etc `

Comment: Something like that. If you showed the declaration of `selectedDocs` I could tell you exactly.

Comment: @cgraham720, so it is just a string array... see my edit.

Comment: thank you! this selection process works perfectly now. i just have one more quesiton, since using the list the command `selectedDocs.Length.ToString()` - no longer works. i have tried  `doclist.Length.ToString()`

Comment: @cgraham720, use `doclist.Count`

Comment: the .count displays "5 documents combined" which isn't necessarily correct if only 2/3/4 documents are chosen. i will continue to play around with this and see what i can figure out, thank you for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107073/discussion-between-cgraham720-and-crowcoder).